# PHP & curl_multi and CURLOPT_FILE = No File Contents

Tags: php, curl-multi

when processing calls with the CURLOPT_FILE (sending contents to a file) in parallel (using  curl_mult_exec) the file contents when the contents is small (not sure exact size but in this case its 100 - 300 bytes) is always 0.

After the call finishing i have to call fclose() on the file in order for the contents to be written.

Using normal curl_exec the contents are written properly. I'm using PHP 5.3.10 on ubuntu.

Is this a bug, expected behavior? i can't find anything surrounding this online

Comment: Where is the code you are trying. so we can debug it

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/syBiH8eZ](http://pastebin.com/syBiH8eZ). The code is taken directly from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php, then a few lines added. You'll see an "executeOnComplete" call on line 14. This is where the file is empty. If is close the file at line 14 i will then see file contents

Comment: very good question, is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: I can't imagine this is expected behavior since there is no mention of this behavior & the code I'm using is taken from PHP's website were they DO NOT use fclose().  This is appears like a bug